# Is using a mutex to make a thread exit bad practice?

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

!I am fairly new to multi-threading and am trying to find the best way for a primary thread to kill a child thread. BUT, I would like the child thread to finish the current interation of the loop that it is in. I am considering using a mutex for this but I am very new to mutexs, semaphors, and other inter thread com techniques. For example:

```
extern pthread_mutex_t lock;     // Global Mutex

void * child_thread()
{
    while(!pthread_mutex_trylock(&lock))
    {
         do_stuff();
    }
}


int main()
{
    while(1)
    {
         if(something_happens())
              pthread_mutex_lock(&TX_lock); // Lock mutex to signal thread to finish
    }
}
```

Is this bad practice?

Comment: Mutex is a data synchronisation object, which by itself is not intended for such scenarios. Atomic boolean variable would be nicer for that purpose.

Comment: The pthreads way to do this is with a [condition variable](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/#ConditionVariables).

Answer (score 1):

A simple way would be to use a shared atomic variable.

```
void * child_thread()
{
    while(run)
    {
         do_stuff();
    }
}
```

Set run to false to exit the child thread and call join() in the main. The join() call will block the execution of the main thread until the child thread has finished.

Comment: You still have to protect run with a Mutex.

Comment: @Ben No you don't, as long as only one thread is changing its value. Which in this case is.

Comment: the pthread_mutex_lock also include a memory barrier, if you don't use it, the child thread might not refresh the value from its cache. This is not just theory, it happens in practice.

Comment: @Ben It is called in a loop, at one point the value will be read. There is no way the compiler will optimize the condition out.

Comment: @Ben I'm open to examples that show the problem actually happens.

Comment: I'll see if I can make a simple example (later), but I see no reason for this to be safe on any architecture.

Comment: A data race is when two threads potentially access the same memory location at the same time with at least one writing. Data races are undefined behavior and will break your code in very obscure ways. Saying "Its ok as long as only 1 thread writes" is just plain wrong.

Comment: @nwp Using a boolean as run will not cause the problem. The only time the run is changed is when you set it to true. If the child reads at the same time as the value was changed then it might get incorrect data. But it doesn't matter what it reads. If it reads true then it exits. If it reads false, it does another loop, then it reads again, gets true and then exists. Preventing additional loops was not a constraint here.

Comment: @self The compiler knows nothing about other threads - it is free to compile that loop as `while (1) { ... }` if it sees that `run` is non-zero before entering the loop, and that nothing in the loop modifies `run`. It is not obligated to consider that something else may modify the value. `volatile` attempts to address that, with some measure of success...

Comment: I believe the above code will work if "run" is declared as "volatile sig_atomic_t". The "volatile" should ensure that the latest value is always retrieved by the child thread and the "sig_atomic_t" should ensure that a read/write race condition can't occur.

Comment: Alright, I concede, Imo atomic is the best solution there.

Comment: @SteveEmmerson, `sig_atomic_t` doesn't guarantee cache coherence.  C11's `atomic_flag` (or `_Atomic` friends) are what are needed here.

Comment: Re <<Saying "Its ok as long as only 1 thread writes" is just plain wrong.>> Not at all, @nwp. It's perfectly fine to consider the problem context when evaluating solutions. For example, circular buffers were used by keyboards to communicate with the BIOS because they don't require locks when there is at most one reader and one writer. (We all the answer is isn't ok as long as just one thread writes, but that's another issue.)

Comment: @ikegami Claiming that algorithm X, which worked in the dark ages when you had a single CPU with no caches, will continue to work in modern situations where you have multiple CPUs with multiple cores running multiple threads, with varying guarantees of cache-coherency, varying speeds of memory access (NUMA), etc., is a bit questionable. Also, a circular buffer is considerably different than a single byte/word-sized variable...

Comment: @twalberg, Not questionable at all. Some old algorithms still work perfectly well in such environments. (In contrast, saying that *all* algorithms will continue to work is just plain wrong, but noone said that.)

Comment: Alltough this one-thread-only-writes issue might be a corner case, why leave it to the luck, just protect concurrently accessed variables. It's not such a thing to stay on the secure side, in 99% of the cases you give away nothing and stay safe.

Comment: @alk, There are numerous disadvantages to having useless code. More code to write, debug, read, maintain, and all the issues each of those entail.

Comment: @pilcrow I disagree. If one codes to the c99 standard, then I don't see how a conforming C implementation could negate the "volatile sig_atomic_t" solution given the definition of "volatile" in section 6.7.3, of the abstract machine in section 5.1.2.3, and of sequence points in Annex C. IMO, any implementation that did couldn't claim conformance.

Comment: @SteveEmmerson Fun fact, sig_atomic_t is typedefed as int.

Answer (score 0):

Mutexes are used to protect variable for concurrent access, you shouldn't use them to synchronize threads. 
If you want to inform a thread that it should terminate, you could add one extra variable like this.

```
pthread_mutex_t mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
int done = 0; 


void * child_thread()
{


  for(;;){

    do_stuff(); 

    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    if(done) return NULL; 
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex); 
  }

}


int main()
{
    while(!done)
    {
      if(something_happens()){
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex); 
        done = 1; 
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex); 
      }
    }
}
```

You might also want to look at conditions variables.

Comment: As written, child_thread will leave the mutex locked when "done == 1" — not what you want.  (For example, as written, it will deadlock main() the next time something_happens().)

Comment: Thanks. Fixed it. However, it's unclear what whh4000 is trying to do and I'm guessing a condition variable would be more adequate for the problem is trying to solve.